# List the users in AD security group in sp server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I added an AD security group in a sharepoint site. I want to list the users in this group. I want to do this in SP server instead of AD. Have anyone done this before? Could this be achieved through powershell? Please kindly advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following powershell script to achieve this:

```
$web=get-spweb http://yoursite

$ADGroup = $web.EnsureUser("ADGroup")

$reachedMax = $false

$users =[Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::GetPrincipalsInGroup($web, $ADGroup
, 10,[ref]$reachedMax)
$users
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below commands:
Replace the asterisk (*) with the Security Group

Display on Screen:

```
  Get-ADGroupMember -identity "*" | Select Name
```

Export to CSV:

```
  Get-ADGroupMember -identity "*" | Select Name | Export-CSV -Path C:\Windows\Temp\SecurityGroups.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Link Source: http://itnutt.com/powershell-list-members-of-ad-security-group/